# How do i change from export to set in npm start?

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, yarnpkg, package.json

When trying to run npm start on command prompt I get the error "'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." I understand that export command is valid only for unix and that I have to change from "export" to "set". Where exactly do I make these changes? Is there some kind of a script I can make changes in?

Answer (score 0):

`npm start` is a script you define yourself in `package.json`. If you need to set environment variables in your NPM scripts you can just omit the `set` or `export` and write for example `MY_ENV_VAR=some_value`. If the script calls some other script or dependency, that's where you need to look for the answer.